# Is it possible to use Arch without installing the base package?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to use Arch without installing the base package? 
If not, why is the base package not part of the installation image?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (for example: with [busybox](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/busybox/)) And because it's [huge](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/base/).

Comment: Can i manually install the base packages i want? Because a lot of them i dont need

Comment: Yes, of course. Arch is about freedom. Do what you want. Base is a collection of often used programs for beginners. If you know what do you need and what not, you can picking them.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot install Arch without the *base group*.<sup>1</sup>

The base group comprises packages critical for the system. It must be installed in order for you to have a running system.

You can, however, elect to remove some of the individual packages from the group if you are certain that you will not need them. For example, `mdadm` if you don't require RAID functionality. Obviously, you would want to be certain that these packages are not depends of other critical packages before removing them.

<sup>1.</sup> If you are trying to build a minimal environment, then you can choose to forego installing the entire base group, *as long as* you feed `pacstrap` a complete list of the requisite packages sufficient to create a bootable image.

Comment: Why the must packages are not included by default?

Comment: They *are* included by default: they are even bundled as a group for convenience.

Comment: I mean they are not in the iso image you download from the arch site, that is why the installation guide says to intall the base stuff

Comment: Well, technically, most of them are in the ISO (you wouldn't be able to boot it otherwise). You donwload them because Arch is a rolling release and you always want the newest packages.

Answer (score 1):

`base` is not a package its a group of packages so the issue is with the individual packages. They are included in the package group either because they are needed to boot or are important to administration.

The iso is a pre-install environment and is intended to provide a system that can install Arch Linux. It could contain packages via cache but most of the time it contains no packages.

Aside from files you create and a few directories created by `pacstrap` the entire system is installed via packages that are downloaded by `pacman`. The directories pacman creates are just for mountpoints and pacman cache.